# How do I determine whether a branch is the default branch in a jenkins file?

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

We have a multibranch pipeline on jenkins.

I know one can check whether a branch matches the name e.g.

```
when {
    branch "master"
}
```

Unfortunately our default branch is not named master and the name of the default branch changes regularly.

Is there a way to check if a given branch is the default branch without checking the name?

```
when {
    branch is default
}
```

or something like this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think this will work without the name. There is no real 'default' branch in git so Jenkins can only seperate by branch name or another expression like regex.

Comment: @mkemmerz Ok that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: 'Default' branch is a feature of GitHub, but not git afaik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the API of your SCR to get the default branch. Depending on what SCR you use, the call to the API will be different.

In GitLab, you can query the [Project REST API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#get-single-project) and in the response you will find a `default_branch` field containing this information

`GET /projects/:id`

In GitHub, you can query the [Repositories REST API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get) and in the response you will find  a `default_branch` field containing this info as well.

`GET /repos/:owner/:repo`

Be careful with the GitHub response because it contains 3 fields named `default_branch`, one for the actual repo, one for the parent repo, and the last one for the source repo. You are looking for the one on the root of the json, which is the one for the repo you are querying.

Answer (score 6):

Since version 2.6.4 of the Branch API plugin (released in May), Jenkins multibranch pipelines now have access to [a `BRANCH_IS_PRIMARY` environment variable](https://github.com/jenkinsci/branch-api-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/jenkins/branch/BranchNameContributor/buildEnv.properties#L24):

> For a multibranch project, if the SCM source reports that the branch being built is a primary branch, this will be set to `"true"`; else unset.

This means you can now do this instead:

```
when {
    expression { env.BRANCH_IS_PRIMARY }
}
```

Note that you must access it as a property of `env` or alternatively use string interpolation (i.e. "$BRANCH_IS_PRIMARY"), since a `BRANCH_IS_PRIMARY` may not be set ([see discussion](https://github.com/jenkinsci/branch-api-plugin/pull/246#discussion_r623144258)).

Comment: Thank you for this, I knew the env.BRANCH_IS_PRIMARY but searched for replacing the corresponding `when { branch = 'main' }`.  
This should be the accepted answer now.

Answer (score 3):

```
git ls-remote -q --symref | head -1
```

This is a workaround as Gitlab & co use Remote HEAD to mark the "default branch"
We can get remote references with "git ls-remote -q --symref".

Remote head will be the first line, so we can pick first line with pipe head -1.
This gives us the Hash of the "default branch".

Comment: The solution from @matus with REST api is way better than mine here, if you have access to it. unfortunately in my environment the access to rest api is blocked for security reasons.