# Bash git ls-remote know which is the main branch

Tags: linux, bash, git, branch, git-branch

I use the following command to know all the remote branches of a project:

`git ls-remote https://github.com/nanashili/AuroraEditor --h --sort origin "refs/heads/*" | sed "s,.*${TAB}refs/heads/,,"`

But I would like to know which is the main branch of the project, which can be different from main and master.

Can you give me a hand?

Comment: There's technically no main branch, it's just a convention.

Comment: Most probably you want the default branch; it's where `HEAD` points at on the remote repository; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60188813/7976758 ; Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%22ls-remote%22+default+branch

Comment: @RomainValeri: I know, but consider the following example.
You have a project, there are several branches in this project, but none of them are called `main` and `master`.
For example the following link: https://github.com/nanashili/AuroraEditor

When you `git clone` the following project, the project is automatically checked out automatically on the one defined as main eg on` github`.

Comment: Yep, exactly: `git ls-remote -q --symref https://github.com/nanashili/AuroraEditor | head -1` -> "ref: refs/heads/development-main        HEAD"

Comment: @phd: I managed to do this:
`git ls-remote -q --symref https://github.com/nanashili/AuroraEditor | head -1 | sed "s,.*${TAB}refs/heads/,,"`

I get this: `development-main HEAD`

I would like to get just the name without the space after and the word `HEAD`
That is this: `development-main`
do you know how I can do?

Comment: `git ls-remote -q --symref https://github.com/nanashili/AuroraEditor | awk 'NR==1 { print $2; }'` ; `NR==1` selects Record Number 1 (the 1st line); `$2` prints the second field of the 3 space/tab-separated fields.

Comment: @phd: What do you think like this:
`git ls-remote -q --symref https://github.com/nanashili/AuroraEditor | awk 'NR==1 { print $2; }' | sed "s,.*${TAB}refs/heads/,,"`

Comment: @TTT: Then give me an example repository so I can try?

Comment: I'm interested in having at least one.

Comment: @Paul actually I think it just points to one, so I deleted my comment. The rest are probably manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git ls-remote -q --symref <remote> | head -1
```

prints where the `HEAD` points at in the remote repository. `<remote>` can be a name like `origin` or an URL. To cut the full ref name out of the result run

```
git ls-remote -q --symref <remote> | awk 'NR==1 { print $2; }'
```

`NR==1` selects Record Number 1 (the first line); `$2` prints the second field of the 3 space/tab-separated fields. If you want to cut the short branch name instead of the full:

```
git ls-remote -q --symref <remote> | awk 'NR==1 { print $2; }' | sed 's!^refs/heads/!!'
```

Example:

```
$ git ls-remote -q --symref https://github.com/nanashili/AuroraEditor | awk 'NR==1 { print $2; }' | sed 's!^refs/heads/!!'
development-main
```

Or avoiding `awk` completely:

```
git ls-remote -q --symref <remote> | head -1 | cut -f1 | sed 's!^ref: refs/heads/!!'
```

Comment: Is there a way without using print ?

Comment: @Paul Why? You do want to get the output, don't you?

Comment: The problem I have to use it on Swift, I have a package that checks the syntax.
It recognizes print as swift's print, albeit a string, but it gives me trouble.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXbDI.png

Comment: @Paul Brouhaha, broken syntax checker, take my sympathy! Replace `awk` with `cut` and `sed`. See the updated answer.

Comment: Ok, it seems to work, I was trying a similar thing:
`git ls-remote -q --symref https://github.com/nanashili/AuroraEditor | head -1 | sed "s,.*${TAB}refs/heads/,," | sed "s,HEAD,,"`,  but yours works.

Comment: One thing being that I would like to keep the same syntax, in your opinion this is correct, to know all the remote branches?
`git ls-remote https://github.com/nanashili/AuroraEditor --h --sort origin "refs/heads/*" | cut -f2 | sed 's!^refs/heads/!!'`

Comment: @Paul `git ls-remote --heads` See [`git help ls-remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote)

Comment: FWIW : `git ls-remote -q --symref origin HEAD | grep -Po "(?<=ref: refs/heads/)[^\t]*"`

Comment: The additions are : 1. specify we only want `HEAD` from remote, 2. use only "grep" instead of "head -n" (head -1 adds a "remote end hung up unexpectedly" warning in my terminal), 3. write a one stop grep command, with `-o` to isolate the short name of the branch (I got the `-P` and `(?<=...)` shenanigans from [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15136585/86072))

Answer (score 0):

Plain Git doesn't have a term as `main` branch. In GitHub, for example, you can choose `main`, but it will be used on GitHub servers only, your git repository will not change.
So to solve the problem, you can make `main` branch configurable in your script using config file or arguments.

Comment: I know, but consider the following example.
You have a project, there are several branches in this project, but none of them are called `main` and `master`.
For example the following link: https://github.com/nanashili/AuroraEditor

When you `git clone` the following project, the project is automatically checked out automatically on the one defined as main eg on` github`.

Comment: Then you can use HEAD pointer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726037/what-determines-default-branch-after-git-clone

Answer (score 0):

Understanding that the main branch can be *any* branch in a repo, the only thing that can get you *close* to know what branch is the main branch would be (I think) by checking HEAD from the remote, then check the branches in the remote and see which branch is on that revision.... the problem is that there might be more than one branch pointing at that revision.